# Astyanax Composite Keys in Cassandra

Tags: cassandra

Im trying to create a schema that will enable me access rows with only part of the row_key.
For example the key is of the form user_id:machine_os:machine_arch

An example of a row key:   12242:"windows2000":"x86"

From the documentation I could not understand whether this will enable me to query all rows that have userid=12242 or query all rows that have "windows2000"

Is there any feasible way to achieve this ?

Thanks,

Yadid

Comment: Can you share with us the structure of your column family. Also, which part of the row key do you want to use for your retrieval?

Comment: my column family is composed of column names that are Longs and values that are strings. The column names are log timestamps and the values are log entries. Im using a LongType comperator for the columns.

Comment: And what is your composite key? If you've created the col family in CQL, can you provide the describe output.

Comment: that's exactly my problem - im not using CQL, but rather the thrift interface to create and access the data. here is the describe output of my data: CREATE TABLE datacf (
  key bigint,
  key2 text,
  key3 text,
  column1 bigint,
  value blob,
  PRIMARY KEY ((key, key2, key3), column1)
) WITH COMPACT STORAGE AND
  bloom_filter_fp_chance=0.010000 AND
  caching='KEYS_ONLY' AND
  comment='' AND
  dclocal_read_repair_chance=0.000000 AND
  gc_grace_seconds=864000 AND
  read_repair_chance=0.100000 AND
  replicate_on_write='true' AND
  populate_io_cache_on_flush='false' AND......

Comment: You need (at least) the entire partition key to find a piece of data.  Otherwise you won't even know which node/s in the cluster to ask for your data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, here is what is happening: based on your schema, you are effectively creating a column family with a *composite primary key* or a *composite rowkey*. What this means is, you will need to restrict each component of the composite key except the last one with a *strict equality relation*. The last component of the composite key can use inequality and the `IN` relation, but not the 1st and 2nd components.

Additionally, you *must* specify all three parts if you want to utilize any kind of filtering. This is necessary because without all parts of the partition key, the coordinator node will have no idea on which node in the cluster the data exists (remember, Cassandra uses the partition key to determine replicas and data placement).

Effectively, this means you can't do any of these:

```
select * from datacf where user_id = 100012; # missing 2nd and 3rd key components
select * from datacf where user_id = 100012; and machine_arch = 'x86'; # missing 3rd key component
select * from datacf where machine_arch = 'x86'; # you have to specify the 1st
select * from datacf where user_id = 100012 and machine_arch in ('x86', 'x64'); # nope, still want 3rd
```

However, you will be able to run queries like this:

```
select * from datacf where user_id = 100012 and machine_arch = 'x86'
   and machine_os = "windows2000"; # yes! all 3 parts are there

select * from datacf where user_id = 100012 and machine_os = "windows2000"
   and machine_arch in ('x86', 'x64'); # the last part of the key can use the 'IN' or other equality relations
```

To answer your initial question, with you existing data model, you will neither be able to query data with `userid = 12242` or query all rows that have "windows2000" as the `machine_os`.

If you can tell me exactly what kind of query you will be running, I can probably help in trying to design the table accordingly. Cassandra data models usually work better when looked at from the data retrieval perspective. Long story short- use only `user_id` as your primary key and use secondary indexes on other columns you want to query on.

Comment: thanks a lot @Nikhil, this is a lot clearer now ! I was hoping to run queries such as select all records for user X, or select all records that have windows2000. I fear that by using secondary indexes the size of my data may become an issue (lot and lots of small entries). Another option would be to create my own indexes and maintain them manually, right ?

Comment: @user2843110 I don't know the size of your data, but Cassandra was designed to handle _massive sizes_ of data, so I would try with secondary indexes first and measure performance before exploring manual indexes. I will update my answer with more details.